# Add-on Development: Variable pairs with parameters

Tags: add-on, module, parameters

I can't seem to find any documentation or examples of how to give variable pairs parameters in EE add-ons. I have a module working like a charm. Inside the main module tagpair there's a variable pairs like this:

```
{exp:mod:method}

    <h1>{top_level_var}</h1>
    {var_pair}
        <p>{var_pair_variable}</p>
    {/var_pair}

{/exp:mod:method}
```

Boom, that's awesome. But sometimes I want to limit the output of the {var_pair} tag via params like this:

```
{exp:mod:method}

    <h1>{top_level_var}</h1>
    {var_pair limit="7" number="42"}
        <p>{var_pair_variable}</p>
    {/var_pair}

{/exp:mod:method}
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Does EE natively support such params?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not natively supported in ExpressionEngine. The "official" was to do something similar to this would be to simply use additional module tags. Is there a reason you would not want to do that?

```
{exp:mod:method}

    <h1>{top_level_var}</h1>
    {exp:mod:var_pair limit="7" number="42"}
        <p>{var_pair_variable}</p>
    {/exp:mod:var_pair}

{/exp:mod:method}
```

You can use the session cache trick to keep track of shared values between the two module tags when doing this. Place this in your module's constructor:

```
$this->EE = &get_instance();
if(!isset($this->EE->session->cache[__CLASS__]))
{
    $this->EE->session->cache[__CLASS__] = array();
}
$this->cache = &$this->EE->session->cache[__CLASS__];
```

You can then use **$this->cache** as an array anywhere in your tags to keep track of shared data, such as the recordset initially loaded by the outer {exp:mod:method} module tag.

Comment: Also note that any add-ons/official modules which do this resort to using nasty regexes. ALWAYS best to avoid this and use a separate method like Isaac suggests.

Comment: Nice. Wouldn't you have to have `parse="inward"` on the outer method?

Comment: Modules are basically always parse="inward", from the perspective of which tags are parsed first. It's sort of complicated to explain in a comment, but the default behavior without parse="inward" that applies to parse order only takes effect if a nested tag is a plugin. Otherwise, the inner tag is always parsed after the outer tag. This does not apply to the secondary effect of parse="inward" on module or plugin calls embedded in template tag parameters, however. For that to work, parse="inward" must still be set.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look in the EE source code or a module like Playa to see how they are doing it...

Apart from having a separate adding a tag to your module, you can manually search and parse those tags yourself. If you check the sourcecode for the channel module, you can find the following snippet of code used for the categories tag:

```
if (strpos($this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, LD.'/categories'.RD) !== FALSE)
{
  if (preg_match_all("/".LD."categories(.*?)".RD."(.*?)".LD.'\/'.'categories'.RD."/s", $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata, $matches))
  {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($matches[0]); $j++)
    {
      $cat_chunk[] = array($matches[2][$j], $this->EE->functions->assign_parameters($matches[1][$j]), $matches[0][$j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of assigning the result to `$cat_chunk` you can do you own parsing and replacement of that tag.

This does however add a lot of extra code because you wouldn't be able to use the `$this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables` method anymore since you will have to parse everything manually (not just the var_pairs).

Something like this:

```
//  Parse single variables
foreach ($this->EE->TMPL->var_single as $key => $val)
{
  $value = isset($data[$key]) ? isset($data[$key]) : '';
  $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->swap_var_single($key, $data[$key], $tagdata);
}

//  Parse variable pairs
foreach ($this->EE->TMPL->var_pairs as $key => $val)
{
  //  parse categories
  if (strpos($key, 'your_var_pair') !== FALSE)
  {
    // do something with the tag pair
  }
}
```

In this case the `$val` variable should hold your custom parameters.

That being said... the question you should be asking: "Is it all worth the trouble?". Will people (or you) ever use those parameters, because it does add a lot of overhead in the code. There are other tags you will need to parse manually like `{switch=''}`, `{count}` and `{total_results}`.

My answer got a bit longer than I intended, but it **IS** a complex matter.

– Wouter